# Typed text showed on central-top part of screen

Tags: ui

I have a brand new MacBook Air, last night I updated to 10.15.6.
Now, every time I type something, it gets replicated on the top, central part of my screen, above all other windows.

I can even select it, delete/copy/cut, and even write some new.

If there's nothing on it, I can double-click in that area and get a cursor to type new letters.

I've posted two screencaptures to see what I mean.

Any hints?

[image]

[image]