# Mysterious bar appears on top of desktop

Tags: macos, mac, desktop

I have recently been seeing everything I type in my Safari search bar appear in a narrow bar on top of my desktop. You can see an example below:

[image]

What is the cause and how to fix it.

Comment: This would appear to be a similar issue to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399259/typed-text-showed-on-central-top-part-of-screen but not even a comment on it yet.

Comment: It looks a little bit like 'Hover Text' is enabled: System Preferences → Accessibility → Zoom → Enable Hover Text. It's not quite the same, but it's worth checking.

Comment: @TedWrigley I have a bunch of options in Zoom, non of which is "Enable Hover Text". I only have "Smooth images" enabled in Zoom. BTW I'm working with macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Comment: Ah, sorry; I thought you were on Catalina. Did they really have a Siri menu bar item in Mojave? At any rate, try restarting in Safe Mode (hold down the `Shift` key when you restart your mac) and see if the problem persists. if it doesn't, it might be a third-party app creating the text box. Does it do anything if you click on it?

Comment: @TedWrigley I can select it and type or delete the characters. It is gone in the safe mode. I haven't installed anything recently, so it should either be a malware or I have change some app's settings. Any way to narrow it down?

Comment: I doubt it's malware; how dumb would that be? It seems like *feature* of something that's gone awry. Does it only happen in Safari, or does it occur in other apps (Apple apps like TextEdit; third party apps like Chrome)?

Comment: @TedWrigley It has disappeared after I left safe mode and booted regularly. Problem is solved, I guess! I'll update if it appeared again.